# Loop through rows and match values in SQL

Tags: sql

appreciate any help with my problem! I have an org chart of all employees and then columns for their supervisors. I am trying to find the first in the org structure supervisor for each employee that has 3+ years' experience. So if supervisor 1 has only 1 year, I will need to move to the next column with super visor 2 and see if they have more experience. At the end, I would like to return a column of supervisors' ids [experienced_supervisor column]

Table: org_chart

```
   id   |  experience   | supervisor_id_1| supervisor_id_2 | experienced_supervisor
    A   |      2        |     X          |    C            |    X
    C   |      5        |     V          |    D            |    D
    V   |      1        |     M          |    X            |    M
    X   |      3                            
    D   |      8
    M   |      11
```

I am new to SQL and not even sure if this is the best approach. But here is my thinking: I will use CASE to look though every row (employee) and compare their supervisor's experience.

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN  experience >=3   THEN   supervisor_id_1 
     ELSE 
       CASE WHEN  experience >=3   THEN   supervisor_id_2
       ELSE 'not found'
     END AS experienced_supervisor
FROM org_chart
```

Questions:

- Is this the best way to tackle the problem?
- Can I look up the value [experience years] of supervisors by matching supervisor_id_1, supervisor_id_2 to id? Or do I need to create a new column supervisor_id_1_experience and fill the years of experience by doing the join?

I am using Redshift.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why Should I Tag My RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/)

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `case` expression, but a lot of `join`s or subqueries.  Perhaps

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (SELECT oc2.experience >=3 FROM org_chart oc2 WHERE oc2.id = supervisor_id_1) >= 3
             THEN supervisor_id_1 
             WHEN (SELECT oc2.experience >=3 FROM org_chart oc2 WHERE oc2.id = supervisor_id_2) >= 3
             THEN supervisor_id_2 
             . . .
        END) AS experienced_supervisor
FROM org_chart oc
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and errors here is the result that worked for my problem. I am using Redshift in this case.

```
-- Use common table expression to find job level for each supervisor from reporting levels 8 to 2
WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT B.id as employee
      ,B.experience as employee_experience
      ,B.supervisor_id_1 as manager_1
      ,A.experience as supervisor_1_experience
      FROM org_chart
      INNER JOIN org_chart B ON B.supervisor_id_1 = A.id
),
cte2 AS
(
SELECT B.id as employee2
      ,B.experience as employee_experience
      ,B.supervisor_id_2 as manager_2
      ,A.experience as supervisor_2_experience
      FROM org_chart
      INNER JOIN org_chart B ON B.supervisor_id_2 = A.id
),
........-- Write as many statements as I have columns with reporting levels
-- Join all tables above
cte3 AS
(
SELECT employee
       ,employee_experience
       ,manager_1
       ,supervisor_1_experience
       ,manager_2
       ,supervisor_2_experience
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON cte2.employee2 = cte1.employee
....... -- Write as many statements as I have columns with reporting levels
)
-- Run through every row and evaluate if each supervisor has more than 3 years of experience 
SELECT *
,CASE
WHEN cte3.supervisor_1_experience >= 3 THEN cte3.manager_1
WHEN cte3.supervisor_1_experience < 3
          AND cte3.supervisor_2_experience >=3
          THEN cte3.manager_2
........ -- Write as many statements as I have columns with reporting levels
END experienced_supervisor
FROM cte3
```